Board-To-Board Connector : Shield Pins : Voltage Bus?
Question
On a board-to-board connector, can the shield pins be used as power pins to carry bus voltage, or should shield pins always be tied to return?
Specific Connector
In my specific case, the connector pair are low-profile mezzanine connectors (plug, receptacle).
The datasheet specifies:
i.max.signal = 0.3 [A]
i.max.power  = 5.0 [A]

however, the datasheet nor the drawing specify a power pin.
The manufacturer provided symbols/footprints are as follows:
Plug:

Receptacle:

Note that the plug specifies the end pins as power pins whereas the receptacle specifies the end pins as shield pins. The manufacturer responded for clarification that the 'fixturing pins' are the high current rating power pins advertised in the datasheet.
The manufacturer provided a diagram of the fixturing pins as well:


Specific Case
I have 3x dc bus voltages:
V1  = 4.0 [V], 1.50 [A.max]
V2  = 3.0 [V], 0.50 [A.max]
V3  = 3.8 [V], 0.25 [A.max]
RTN = 3.8 [V], 2.25

They share a return.
The max voltage anywhere near them will be 12 [V].
The connector is current-rated as:
5.00 0.30 0.30 0.30 5.00
[P1] [11] [12] [13] [P2]
[  ] [21] [22] [23] [  ]
     0.30 0.30 0.30

I thought I could hook it up with currents such that:
1.50 0.25 0.25 0.25 2.25
[V1] [V3] [V2] [V2] [RTN]
[  ] [V3] [V2] [V2] [   ]
     0.25 0.25 0.25


@DavideAndrea : The manufacturer description of the part in each of the provided links uses those labels.

Sorry. I edited my question after you replied. I know that that's what Amphenol calls them. But I'd like to know your though process independently of what Amphenol calls them, please.

@jsotola. Thank you. I wish I were allowed to edit my mistake. All I can do is delete the whole comment.

That is a hybrid connector (signal contacts plus power contacts). They are not shield contacts. The power contacts are available to carry the power supply current. So, yes, do use one for power and one for return.
EDIT. Upon further inspection of the spec sheet, it appears that Amphenol considers the outer contacts as mechanical supports ("fixing tabs"), not as power circuits and not as shield contacts. Yet, why gold-plate mechanical supports if they are not intended to carry current?

Is there any reason why the product specification on the site makes no mention of the power pins? It says 6 pins (not 8 nor 6 + 2 power). The datasheet mentions the power pin ratings .. but does not mention them existing anywhere. It's strange.

I am afraid I may have been wrong. Not sure. Please see my edits.

I remain equally as confused by their documentation :/ But their representative confirmed that the mechanical supports are the pins which carry a 5.0 [A] rating.

Diagrams added to question for further clarification.

@kando. Very useful information. I learned more from your question that you from my answer. Thank you.
